# Clean solution on open in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can I setup Visual Studio so that whenever I open a solution, once the solution has been opened, it will perform a "Clean Solution"?

Comment: You most likely will be able to write a macro that does that for you. However, I am wondering what the actual problem is that you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: A bug in visual studio where it will retain references to two copies of a dll, causing the visual designer to fail when a control you are using is in one of those dll's because it is referencing two of them. Whenever this happens need to close and reopen studio, clean the project and then do a build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this functionality in this form does not exist.

Thomas